# Autosys : minimal JIL File

Tags: linux, autosys, jil

I am new to AutoSys.

Here is simplistic JIL file I have created, but it keeps erroring out with following :

**jil - ERROR - Redirect failed.**

```
insert_job: summary_report      job_type: CMD
command: $BIN_DIR/summary_report.sh
machine: www.XXXXX.com
owner: uowner
days_of_week: all
start_times: "16:30"
description: "Database Report"
timezone: Newyork
```

Any clues ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
insert_job: summary_report    job_type: cmd
description: Database Report
machine: xxx
owner: xxx
max_run_alarm: 0
alarm_if_fail: y
date_conditions: y
timezone: Newyork
days_of_week: su,mo,tu,we,th,fr,sa
start_times: "16:30"
send_notification: n
command: $BIN_DIR/summary_report.sh
```

Well the JIL seems to be correct, i was able to upload at my end.

Attribute i had modified are job name , machine and owner.